# C++ Determine security type (WEP or WPA) using linux library iwlib?

Tags: c++, wifi, wpa, wep

I need to create wpa_supplicant.conf for different type of encryption(WEP, WPA and NONE). I'm scanning for available AP using iwlib and wireless events. Problem is that i can't find security type in scanning result. How to do that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i find the answer.
If AP broadcast general IE(information element) and it's 8's byte is 0x01...0x05 - AP has WPA or WPA2, if 8's byte has value 0x4a - AP support WPS. If AP broadcasting  only  WPS IE or if there are no IE - AP has WEP key.

Comment: Where is that information? I cannot find it. It seems I'd have to re-implement iw_scan() to get that information. Is that correct?